# What is the is the difference between -copyFromLocal and -put

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, bigdata

Is it possible to explain difference between -copyFromLocal and -put command in Hadoop. I am not able to find any good document which says the difference between two commands.

Answer (score 1):

Well one can explain if there is a difference and i don't think there is.
Look at the code below all that CopyFromLocal does is extends Put with no additional functionality.

```
public static class CopyFromLocal extends Put {

    public static final String NAME = "copyFromLocal";
    public static final String USAGE = Put.USAGE;
    public static final String DESCRIPTION = "Identical to the -put command.";
  }
```

https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/fs/shell/CopyCommands.java

Comment: Answer already exists. See comment above